# Hybris SOLR facet indexed property not showing

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud, solrj

I've created a new SOLR Indexed property that must act as category a facet:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty; solrIndexedType(identifier)[unique = true]; name[unique = true]; type(code); multiValue[default = true]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code); facetSort(code); priority; visible; categoryField[default = true]; fieldValueProvider             ; facetDisplayNameProvider         ; topValuesProvider
                             ; $solrIndexedType                          ; color              ; string    ;                           ;                      ; MultiSelectOr  ; Alpha          ; 4000    ; true   ;                              ; colorCategoryNameValueProvider ; categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider ; defaultTopValuesProvider
```

I've created the custom value provider:

```
    <bean id="colorCategoryNameValueProvider" parent="abstractCategoryNameValueProvider">
    <property name="categorySource" ref="colorCategorySource" />
</bean>

<bean id="colorCategorySource" parent="abstractCategorySource">
    <property name="rootCategory" value="color" />
</bean>
```

I've performed a full index and I SOLR Admin I can see the new indexed field populated:

```
"color_string_mv":["MultiColor",
      "Color"],
```

However, when I go to PLP/Grid I only see one facet, which is price.

As you can see in the impex, the SolrIndexedPropert isFacet attribute is set to TRUE and is also being populated in SOLR database, why hybris is not detecting this facet and displaying it in the storefront?

Comment: this link may help :https://answers.sap.com/questions/13018410/custom-attribute-facets-are-not-displaying-in-stor.html

Comment: Didn't help since I'm creating a facet that is using category value provider instead of numeric one

Comment: @Nexussim Lements Check whether products have different colors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was found:

Along with the SolrIndexedProperty, in order to display the facet I must add the facets attributes as:

```
INSERT_UPDATE SolrSearchQueryProperty; indexedProperty(name, solrIndexedType(identifier))[unique = true]; searchQueryTemplate(name, indexedType(identifier))[unique = true][default = DEFAULT:$solrIndexedType]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code); includeInResponse[default = true]; facetDisplayNameProvider             ; facetSortProvider; facetTopValuesProvider
                                 ; categoryPath:$solrIndexedType                                    ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; Refine         ;                                  ;                                      ;
                                 ; category:$solrIndexedType                                        ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; Refine         ;                                  ; categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider ; defaultTopValuesProvider
                                 ; brand:$solrIndexedType                                           ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; MultiSelectOr  ;                                  ; categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider ; defaultTopValuesProvider
                                 ; color:$solrIndexedType                                           ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; MultiSelectOr  ;                                  ; categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider ; defaultTopValuesProvider
                                 ; size:$solrIndexedType                                            ;                                                                                                      ;                      ; MultiSelectOr  ;                                  ; categoryFacetDisplayNameProvider ; defaultTopValuesProvider
```

Answer (score 1):

If all the products in the result have the same value or no value at all, the facet won't show. The facet will only appear if it will make a difference in the result when the user filters by it. Can you check if that's the case?